# How to add non-Haskell dependencies to a cabal2nix generated shell.nix

Tags: haskell, nix

I use cabal2nix to generate shell.nix files. However I can't figure out how to add non-Haskell package dependencies to a shell.nix file.

Below is a simple shell.nix file example generated by `cabal2nix --shell`. How would I edit it to do what I want?

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {}).pkgs;
let pkg = haskellngPackages.callPackage
            ({ mkDerivation, base,
             , cabal-install}:
             mkDerivation {
               pname = "testing";
               version = "0.1.0.0";
               src = ./.;
               buildDepends = [ base cabal-install];
               license = stdenv.lib.licenses.publicDomain;
             }) {};
in
  pkg.env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buildDepends` attribute is not specific to cabal, it's present in all nix derivations. So you just need to add your dependencies to that array. For example, if you need `ffmpeg` for some reason, just write:

```
buildDepends = [ base cabal-install ffmpeg ];
```